# SQL-Server trigger update issue from over linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server

I would like to update rows over linked server. I created linked server on my local SQL-Server with [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=21644) instruction.

I can update rows over Query Analyzer with below code. No error returned and rows update on Linked Server successfully.

```
UPDATE  [LinkedServer].[Database].[dbo].[Table]
SET A = 'A', B = 'B'
WHERE id = 1
```

But when I created a update trigger to my table on my local sql server like below,

```
ALTER TRIGGER [TriggerLocalServerTable]
   ON  dbo.[LocalServerTable]
    FOR UPDATE
AS 

DECLARE @A varchar(4)
DECLARE @B varchar(4)
DECLARE @id int

BEGIN
 SELECT
 @A = A,
 @B = B,
 @id = id
 FROM inserted

 UPDATE  [LinkedServer].[Database].[dbo].[Table]
 SET A = @A, B = @B
 WHERE id = @id      
END
```

When trigger performed, returns this error like below,

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked
>   server "LinkedServer" returned message
>   "The partner transaction manager has
>   disabled its support for
>   remote/network transactions.". Msg
>   7391, Level 16, State 2, Procedure
>   TriggerLocalServerTable, Line 45
>   The operation could not be performed
>   because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for
>   linked server "LinkedServer" was unable
>   to begin a distributed transaction.

I applied [this](http://www.sqlwebpedia.com/content/msdtc-troubleshooting) instruction to local server for solving issue, anything changed.

More details;

- if defined my linked server with its
  remote ip address.
- My local server and Linked Server
  not in same domain.
- Linked Server Security setting is "Be
  made using this security context"
- Local server version is Windows
  Server 2003 SP2, SQL-Server version is 2005 
  standart.
- Linked server OS version is 2008 and
  SQL-Server version 2008 (64 bit).
- I couldn't access remote server
  with RDP. i can access just from sql
  port (1433).
- i set linked server    "RPC" and "RPC
  Out" to "True" from    "Security Option".

Do you have any idea to solve this issue.
Thank you very much already now.

**Edit:** 
I solved this issue. Firstly i created a trigger for update on [TriggerLocalServerTable]. This trigger's job is inserting new update fields to a local table. This new table using for updated temp datas. Then i created a job that runs every hour for update fileds on LinkedServer. This job gets data from temp table then update to LinkedServer table's fields.

Regards, Kerberos.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a Distributed Transaction Coordinator installed on Windows Server? If your update is inside a transaction, it won't work without it.
See
[link text](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/sql-server/how-to-configure-dtc-on-windows-2008/)

Comment: Yes, it installed on local server and "Distributed Transaction Coordinator" servis statue is "started". But if you ask about linked server, i don't know. Because i could'nt access this server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem dont lies with SQL Server it is with ODBC Driver.

- Go to Start > Settings > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Data Sources
- Open System DSN Tab
- Select the driver you have used for Linked Server and click configure
- Select Advanced > Flags3 and Uncheck Disable transaction check box

Problem Solved :)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the answer.  The original poster (OP) already provided the answer in an Edit to the question.

Comment: There is three DNS..
USER DNS,System DNS and File DNS whixch one I will use